# don´t create duplicated objects. django, python

Tags: python, django, command

I created a script to avoid creating duplicate objects but it still created the same objects when I run the command 3 times it creates them 3 times over and over again. I would like you to help me and know what is wrong with my code.

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from jobs.models import Job
import json
from datetime import datetime
import dateparser


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Set up the database'

    def handle(self, *args: str, **options: str):
        with open('static/newdata.json', 'r') as handle:
            big_json = json.loads(handle.read())
            for item in big_json:
                if len(item['description']) == 0:
                    print('Not created. Description empty')
                    continue

                dt = dateparser.parse(item['publication_date'])

                existing_job = Job.objects.filter(

                    job_title = item['job_title'],
                    company = item['company'],
                    company_url = item['company_url'],
                    description = item['description'],
                    publication_date = dt,
                    salary = item['salary'],
                    city = item['city'],
                    district = item['district'],
                    job_url = item['job_url'],
                    job_type = item['job_type'],

                )
                if existing_job.exists() is True:
                    print('This Job already exist')
                else:
                    Job.objects.create(

                        job_title = item['job_title'],
                        company = item['company'],
                        company_url = item['company_url'],
                        description = item['description'],
                        publication_date = dt,
                        salary = item['salary'],
                        city = item['city'],
                        district = item['district'],
                        job_url = item['job_url'],
                        job_type = item['job_type'],

                )

                self.stdout.write(self.style.SUCCESS('added jobs!'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using built-in field validation `unique=True`?
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#unique

Comment: mmm no because all field has to be the same to avoid duplication. 2 jobs can have the same title but be different in the rest o fields

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if existing_job.exists():
```

instead of

```
if existing_job.exists() is True:
```

because .exists() returns boolean itself

Comment: yeah. but I got the same result

Comment: as you sad that it's creating objects. so your issue should be in if statement and existing_job. focus on those. you may set points on those lines and debug them

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `unique_together` without the publication_date field? [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/options/#unique-together)

```py
# models.py
class Job(models.Model):
    # Your fields here...

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [[
            'job_title',
            'company',
            'company_url',
            'description',
            'salary',
            'city',
            'district',
            'job_url',
            'job_type'
        ]]
```

Comment: Is it possible that the values are different in a non-obvious way? Different case letters, different spacing perhaps?

Comment: no, they are the same. because I am running the code 3 times from JSON data.

Comment: So I take it you get 3 'versions' of each line from the JSON file?

Comment: I do not understand so much what you're saying. the thing is that when I run the command it creates jobs y those fields. if I run again. it shouldn't create any job because is the same JSON file with the same data.

Comment: When you run the command again, does it create every single line a second time?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225224/discussion-between-karl-and-dp-audiovisual).

Comment: yeah when the script creates the same job the only thing change is the publication_date

Answer (score 0):

```
dt = dateparser.parse(item['publication_date'])
new_date = date(dt.year, dt.month, dt.day)
```

here was the problem. I am scraping the publication date in this format ('1 Week Ago') and then I was changing to a date and time format. and when I run the script again the time of the conversion is a different time. so that's why the job is created again. because is not the same because the time creation